# Fiz um relógio mas o link dele não gira

Tags: javascript, html, css

Esse é o link dele https://biancavieiraa.github.io/Relogio/

```js
const secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand');
const minsHand = document.querySelector('.min-hand');
const hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour-hand');

function setDate() {
  const now = new Date();

  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;

  const mins = now.getMinutes();
  const minsDegrees = ((mins / 60) * 360) + ((seconds/60)*6) + 90;
  minsHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minsDegrees}deg)`;

  const hour = now.getHours();
  const hourDegrees = ((hour / 12) * 360) + ((mins/60)*30) + 90;
  hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegrees}deg)`;
}

setInterval(setDate, 1000);

setDate();
```

```css
html {
    background-image: url(./imagem/background.jpg);
    min-width: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    min-height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .clock {
    width: 30rem;
    height: 30rem;
    border: 7px solid rgb(226, 107, 21);
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 2rem;
    background: rgb(226, 107, 21);
  }
  
  .outer-clock-face {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #fefefc;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .outer-clock-face::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg)
  }
  
  .outer-clock-face::before,
  .outer-clock-face::after,
  .outer-clock-face .marking{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 6px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #134d74ab;
    z-index: 0;
    left: 49%;
  }
  
  .outer-clock-face .marking {
    background: #1b79b8;
    width: 3px;
  }
  
  .outer-clock-face .marking.marking-one {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg)
  }
  
  .outer-clock-face .marking.marking-two {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg)
  }
  
  .outer-clock-face .marking.marking-three {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
    transform: rotate(120deg)
  }
  
  .outer-clock-face .marking.marking-four {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(150deg);
    transform: rotate(150deg)
  }
  
  .inner-clock-face {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    background: #fefefc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .inner-clock-face::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    margin-left: -9px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    background: #134d74ab;
    z-index: 11;
  }
  
  .hand {
    width: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    height: 6px;
    background: #134d74;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transform-origin: 100%;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 2.7, 0.58, 1);
  }
  
  .hand.hour-hand {
    width: 20%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  
  .hand.min-hand {
    height: 3px;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 35%;
  }
  
  .hand.second-hand {
    background: #db3d0d;
    width: 40%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Relógio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="clock">
        <div class="outer-clock-face">
          <div class="marking marking-one"></div>
          <div class="marking marking-two"></div>
          <div class="marking marking-three"></div>
          <div class="marking marking-four"></div>
          <div class="inner-clock-face">
            <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
            <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
            <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não [duplique postagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/566098/70), resolva o motivo de fechamento na pergunta original.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Pra mim abriu normal
Porem o seu HTML faltou o script pra ele pode rodar os ponteiros do relógio.
Crie um script ou chama dentro mesmo.
**index.js**

```js
const secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand');
const minsHand = document.querySelector('.min-hand');
const hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour-hand');

function setDate() {
  const now = new Date();

  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;

  const mins = now.getMinutes();
  const minsDegrees = ((mins / 60) * 360) + ((seconds/60)*6) + 90;
  minsHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minsDegrees}deg)`;

  const hour = now.getHours();
  const hourDegrees = ((hour / 12) * 360) + ((mins/60)*30) + 90;
  hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegrees}deg)`;
}

setInterval(setDate, 1000);

setDate();
```